# Amcharts integration using Javascript in Twig file

Tags: javascript, php, amcharts

I'm attempting to use amCharts in my Twig file, but I'm facing issues with parsing the code. Regardless of what I try, the charts don't seem to work. However, when I place my code outside of the JavaScript loop, I can see that the data is being retrieved correctly.
But I couldn't do this between  tags. No results are returned.

```
<div id="kt_charts_widget_15_chart" class="min-h-auto ps-4 pe-6 mb-3 h-350px"></div>
<script>
    var KTChartsWidget15 = {
        init: function () {
            var e = am5.Root.new("kt_charts_widget_15_chart");
            if (e) {
                var t,
                    a = function () {
                        t = am5.Root.new(e);
                        t.setThemes([am5themes_Animated.new(t)]);

                        var salesData = [
                            {% for data in getLastDays %}
                            {
                                country: {{ data.sales_date }},
                                visits: {{ data.total_sales }},
                                icon: "https://www.amcharts.com/wp-content/uploads/flags/united-states.svg",
                                columnSettings: { fill: am5.color(KTUtil.getCssVariableValue("--bs-primary")) },
                            },
                            {% endfor %}
                        ];

                        var l = t.container.children.push(am5xy.XYChart.new(t, { panX: !1, panY: !1, layout: t.verticalLayout }));

                        var r = l.xAxes.push(
                            am5xy.CategoryAxis.new(t, {
                                categoryField: "country",
                                renderer: am5xy.AxisRendererX.new(t, { minGridDistance: 30 }),
                                bullet: function (e, t, a) {
                                    return am5xy.AxisBullet.new(e, {
                                        location: 0.5,
                                        sprite: am5.Picture.new(e, {
                                            width: 24,
                                            height: 24,
                                            centerY: am5.p50,
                                            centerX: am5.p50,
                                            src: a.dataContext.icon,
                                        }),
                                    });
                                },
                            })
                        );

                        r.get("renderer").labels.template.setAll({ paddingTop: 20, fontWeight: "400", fontSize: 10, fill: am5.color(KTUtil.getCssVariableValue("--bs-gray-500")) });
                        r.get("renderer").grid.template.setAll({ disabled: !0, strokeOpacity: 0 });
                        r.data.setAll(salesData);

                        var o = l.yAxes.push(am5xy.ValueAxis.new(t, { renderer: am5xy.AxisRendererY.new(t, {}) }));
                        o.get("renderer").grid.template.setAll({ stroke: am5.color(KTUtil.getCssVariableValue("--bs-gray-300")), strokeWidth: 1, strokeOpacity: 1, strokeDasharray: [3] });
                        o.get("renderer").labels.template.setAll({ fontWeight: "400", fontSize: 10, fill: am5.color(KTUtil.getCssVariableValue("--bs-gray-500")) });

                        var i = l.series.push(am5xy.ColumnSeries.new(t, { xAxis: r, yAxis: o, valueYField: "visits", categoryXField: "country" }));
                        i.columns.template.setAll({ tooltipText: "{categoryX}: {valueY}", tooltipY: 0, strokeOpacity: 0, templateField: "columnSettings" });
                        i.columns.template.setAll({ strokeOpacity: 0, cornerRadiusBR: 0, cornerRadiusTR: 6, cornerRadiusBL: 0, cornerRadiusTL: 6 });
                        i.data.setAll(salesData);
                        i.appear();
                        l.appear(1000, 100);
                    };

                am5.ready(function () {
                    a();
                });
            }
        },
    };

    "undefined" != typeof module && (module.exports = KTChartsWidget15);

    KTUtil.onDOMContentLoaded(function () {
        KTChartsWidget15.init();
    });
</script>
```